# How to prevent a caller of a method from storing the result in C++

Tags: c++

Assume I have a Singleton class. How can I prevent callers from being able to store the result of the call to getInstance() method?

I need this, since the instance of the singleton can be modified during execution and any stored instance in other classes will be invalidated. My solution would be to force all the callers to call getInstance() every time when they want to use the instance of the Singleton.

```
class Singleton
{
    private:
        static Singleton* instance;

    private:
        Singleton();

    public:
        static Singleton* getInstance();
};

Singleton* Singleton::instance = nullptr;

Singleton* Singleton::getInstance()
{
    if (instance == nullptr)
    {
        instance = new Singleton();
    }

    return instance;
}

class A
{
private:
    Singleton* m_singleton;

public:
    A()
        : m_singleton(Singleton::getInstance()) //This should not be possible
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't prevent the callers from storing the result. Since you give them the pointer, they can do whatever they want with it. You may guard in this case, the methods exposed by this class.

Comment: Maybe just don't define a getInstance()-method, but rather implement a full interface for the singleton's functionality?

Comment: what do you mean by saying "the singleton can be modified"? The instance can be mutated? Or the instance literally could be changed, e.g. two subsequent call to getInstance() will results with something different?

Comment: If you mean that your pointer to the instance might dangle, you are abusing singletons, which are considered already an anti-pattern

Comment: your current approach in getInstance is open to race conditions, return a reference instead `static Singleton instance; return instance;`

Comment: @PasserBy Which pointer? `Singleton::instance` won't be dangling, as far as I read the question, but `A::m_instance` apparently can be, thus always calling `getInstance` shall be enforced (which cannot, of course...).

Comment: @Aconcagua I meant dangle as in the singleton instance might be deleted and created again.

Comment: @PasserBy Sure - then `A::m_instance` will be dangling. This is why the assignment shall be prevented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. If your `getInstance()` returns a pointer or reference, there is no way to prevent the result from being copied into some variable, the same way as you cannot prevent a result of type `int` or `double` from being copied.

You could, however, make the functions the singleton provides static:

```
class SomeSingleton
{
public:
    static void foo();
private:
    // deleting copy constructor and assignment operator...
    static SomeSingleton* getInstance();
};

void SomeSingleton::foo()
{
    SomeSingleton* instance = getInstance();
    // use instance as you need to get the appropriate result
}
```

So you enforce usage like this:

```
SomeSingleton::foo();
```

Some might even consider it more comfortable to use than

```
SomeSingleton::getInstance().foo();
```

By the way: This aproach makes it possible to protect you from race conditions, too, if multi-threading is or gets an issue:

```
class SomeSingleton
{
public:
    static void foo();
private:
    static std::mutex mutex; // <- add a mutex!

    static SomeSingleton* getInstance();

    static void exchange();
};

void SomeSingleton::foo()
{
    // this must be added whenever the singleton is used...
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);

    SomeSingleton* instance = getInstance();
    // use instance as you need to get the appropriate result
}

void SomeSingleton::exchange()
{
    // ... or the singleton instance is re-asigned
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);

    SomeSingleton* newInstance = new SomeSingleton();
    delete instance;
    instance = newInstance;
}
```

Comment: This way, you should expose and forward every member of singleton class. Sounds hard to maintain :/

Comment: @pergy Well, there is no reason not to implement the static function directly... Edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a wrapper with overloaded `->` operator like in smart pointers which calls `getInstance()` inside:

```
class Singleton {
    friend SingletonWrapper;
    private:
        static Singleton * getInstance() {...}
    public:
        void foo() {}
};

class SingletonWrapper {
    public:
    Singleton * operator->() {
        return Singleton::getInstance();
    }
};

int main() {
    SingletonWrapper w;
    w->foo();
}
```

Comment: Will this work if the caller dereferences the result of the getInstance and then stores that as a reference?

Comment: @Vahagn as you can see `getInstance` is private and `SingletonWrapper` can invoke it because it is `Singleton`'s `friend`.

Comment: Just note that operators can be called directly like any other function/method, even `operator->`, so this solution still allows the caller to gain direct access to the actual `Singleton` object and bypass subsequent `getInstance()` calls. [Live demo](http://ideone.com/W23ies)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I wouldn't suggest using pointers for singletons. This (["Meyer Singleton"](https://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/C-plus-plus-In-Theory-The-Singleton-Pattern-Part-I/4/)) is a much better approach.

```
static SingletonDatabase &get() {
   static SingletonDatabase db;
   return db;
}
```

Also storing the singleton is kind of a bad idea, as with the storing you validate the initial idea / purpose behind the singleton: You are making copies, thus the singleton is not the "sole" instance of the class.

Anyway a great solution to your problem would be to use some kind of signal/slot system. (Qt / Boost library) Upon change you can emit the singal, which is then "caught" by all instances and the actualize the values.

[Boost Signals / Slots](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/signals.html)
[Qt Signals Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html)

I Hope this helps :)

Comment: Your Meyer Singleton link is broken

Comment: Although generally agreeing about the pattern, in the specific case we are in trouble as OP wants to be able to exchange the singleton instance (unless exchange can take place within get itself).

Answer (score 0):

Use volatile to declare the singleton variable. This will force the compiler to always check for it

```
class Singleton
{
    private:
        static volatile Singleton* instance;

    private:
        Singleton();

    public:
        static volatile Singleton* getInstance();
};
```